# What is wrong with this code that Windows 8 doesn't like, but Windows 7 runs fine?

Tags: vbscript, windows-8

Have errors on Line 59, Char 1.... "The Interface is Unknown"

The intent is to popup a simple user input box and capture the results into a variable, and then into a text file, so a 3rd party application can read it.  I am not very good at coding VBS but I made this work perfectly in Windows 7.

I am looking to make this (VBscript) work in Windows 8 too.  But I don't want to learn how to script or code in another language.  I don't want to rewrite the whole thing in Javascript or .NET or whatever.

Please let me know what Windows 8 is doing differently from Windows 7 sp1.
Thanks.

```
'=======================[ ASK Password ]========================================'
Option Explicit
Dim strUserID, strPassword

AskPassword

Sub AskPassword()
Dim htmlPwdCode, objCodeFile, objFileSysObj, objBrowser, strButton
Const FOR_WRITING = 2

Set objFileSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

htmlPwdCode = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=" & Chr(34) & "VBScript" & Chr(34) & ">" & Chr(13) & _
"Sub RunScript" & Chr(13) & _
"    OKClicked.Value = " & Chr(34) & "OK"& Chr(34) & Chr(13) & _
"End Sub" & Chr(13) & _
"Sub CancelScript" & Chr(13) & _
"    OKClicked.Value = " & Chr(34) & "Cancelled" & Chr(34) & Chr(13) & _
"End Sub" & Chr(13) & _
"Sub Default_Buttons" & Chr(13) & _
"   If Window.Event.KeyCode = 13 Then" & Chr(13) & _
"       btnOK.Click" & Chr(13) & _
"   End If" & Chr(13) & _
"End Sub" & Chr(13) & _
"</SCRIPT>" & Chr(13) & _
"<BODY onkeypress='vbs:Default_Buttons'><center><font size=" & Chr(34) & "2" & Chr(34) & " face=" & Chr(34) & "Arial" & Chr(34) & ">" & Chr(13) & _
"User name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" & Chr(13) & _
"<input type=" & Chr(34) & "text" & Chr(34) & " name=" & Chr(34) & "UserName" & Chr(34) & " size=" & Chr(34) & "30" & Chr(34) & "><br>" & Chr(13) & _
"Password :&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font><font face=" & Chr(34) & "Arial" & Chr(34) & ">" & Chr(13) & _
"<input type=" & Chr(34) & "password" & Chr(34) & " name=" & Chr(34) & "UserPassword" & Chr(34) & _
" size=" & Chr(34) & "30" & Chr(34) & "></font></p>" & Chr(13) & _
"<input type=" & Chr(34) & "hidden" & Chr(34) & " name=" & Chr(34) & "OKClicked" & Chr(34) & " size = " & Chr(34) & "20" & Chr(34) & ">" & Chr(13) & _
"<input id=" & Chr(34) & "btnOK" & Chr(34) & " class=" & Chr(34) & "button" & Chr(34) & _
" type=" & Chr(34) & "button" & Chr(34) & " value=" & Chr(34) & " OK " & Chr(34) & _
" name=" & Chr(34) & "ok_button" & Chr(34) & " onClick=" & Chr(34) & "RunScript" & Chr(34) & ">" & Chr(13) & _
"<input id=" & Chr(34) & "btnCancel" & Chr(34) & " class=" & Chr(34) & "button" & Chr(34) & _
" type=" & Chr(34) & "button" & Chr(34) & " value=" & Chr(34) & "Cancel" & Chr(34) & _
" name=" & Chr(34) & "cancel_button" & Chr(34) & " onClick=" & Chr(34) & "CancelScript" & Chr(34) & "></center></BODY>"

Set objCodeFile = objFileSysObj.CreateTextFile("LoginPrompt.html", True)
objCodeFile.Write htmlPwdCode
objCodeFile.Close
Set objCodeFile = Nothing

Set objBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objBrowser
    .Height = 200
    .Width = 400
    .Top = 200
    .Left = 300
    .StatusBar = True
    .Toolbar = False
    .Resizable = False
    .Navigate CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName) & "\LoginPrompt.html"
    .Visible = True
End With

Do Until objBrowser.ReadyState = 4
'wait till page loads'
Loop

Do While objBrowser.Document.Body.All.OKClicked.Value = ""
    Wscript.Sleep 50                 
Loop 

strUserID = objBrowser.Document.Body.All.UserName.Value
strPassword = objBrowser.Document.Body.All.UserPassword.Value
strButton = objBrowser.Document.Body.All.OKClicked.Value


'''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim objFSO, strFile, objFile

Const ForWriting = 2
Const OpenAsASCII = 0
Const CreateIfNotExist = True

' Specify output file.
strFile = "C:\TEMP\MEX\UN.txt"

' Open the file.
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, _
ForWriting, CreateIfNotExist, OpenAsASCII)

' write to file.
objFile.WriteLine strUserID

' Clean up.
objFile.Close
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim objFSO2, strFile2, objFile2

Const ForWriting2 = 2
Const OpenAsASCII2 = 0
Const CreateIfNotExist2 = True

' Specify output file.
strFile2 = "C:\TEMP\MEX\PW.txt"

' Open the file.
Set objFSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile2 = objFSO2.OpenTextFile(strFile2, _
ForWriting2, CreateIfNotExist2, OpenAsASCII2)

' write to file.
objFile2.WriteLine strPassword

' Clean up.
objFile2.Close
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''


objBrowser.Quit

If strButton = "Cancelled" Then
    MsgBox "Operation cancelled, script will now exit!"
    Wscript.Quit
Else
    'Credentials accepted for further processing
End If
objFileSysObj.DeleteFile "LoginPrompt.html", True

Set objBrowser = Nothing
Set objFileSysObj = Nothing
End Sub




'=======================[ GOT Password ]========================================'
```

Comment: Please indicate which one is line 59.  And what is this question about?  VBS, VB6 or VB6 migration?  Please don't just slap all tags containing VB onto your question, only the really relevant ones.

Comment: "Do Until objBrowser.ReadyState = 4" is line 59... but even taking it out, results in errors.  Has the syntax changed when running in Win8?

Comment: You need to spend some time debugging this yourself. For example, start deleting lines of code until the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Line 59:  `Do Until objBrowser.ReadyState = 4`

The problem, according to MSDN: [ReadyState Property Example (VBScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), is that the "ReadyState" feature has been removed.